# Is $S^3/S^2$ homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If we define a relation in $\mathbb R^3$
such that, $x$~$y$ iff $x = \alpha y$ with $\alpha >0$, the the quotient space $\mathbb R^3/\mathbb R^+$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

My question is

Let $S^3=\{(x, y, z, w) :x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1\}$ and  $S^2=\{(x, y, z) : x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ then what is the quotient space $S^3/S^2$?

Comment: You haven't defined an equivalence relation on $S^3$ (preferrably one with equivalence classes identifiable with $S^2$), so the questions is rather unclear as it stands.

Comment: Let $X$ be a CW-complex, the quotient space obtained by pinching out the $(n-1)$-th skeleton $X^{(n- 1)}$ in the $n$-th skeleton $X^{(n)}$, is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $n$-spheres, where the number of summands in the wedge is same as the number of $n$-cells of $X$. In this case, $\frac{\Bbb S^3}{\Bbb S^2}\simeq \Bbb S^3\lor \Bbb S^3$.

Comment: It may be useful to consider a small dimensional example. $S^0$ embeds in $S^1$ as two antipodal points, and $S^1/S^0 = S^1\vee S^1$, similarly $S^1$ embeds in $S^2$ as an equator and $S^2/S^1 = S^2\vee S^2$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, The equivalence relation is.. Two points are related if there exist a sphere passing through this points with center at origin.

Comment: Totan Ghosh, in that case all the points of $S^3$ form a single equivalence class, and the quotient space consists of a single point. You need to be very specific. And in the question body. Most viewers won't see it here.

Comment: Is any two point in $S^3$ passing through a sphere whose center at origin? @Jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: Totan Ghosh: Yes. Consider any two points $P$ and $Q$ on $S^3$. The lines $OP$ and $OQ$ span a 2-dimensional subspace $V$ the intersection of $V$ and $S^3$ forms a circle with center at the origin $O$. Surely you can extend that circle to a sphere (of whichever dimension you prefer), so $P$ and $Q$ lie on the surface of a sphere centered at the origin. Exactly what quotient space did you mean?

Comment: Suppose take the points $P$ and $Q$ a line passing through the point, then is your argument is correct? (Of course $P$ and $Q$ are different point)

Comment: Just as any two points on $S^2$ lie on a great circle, every two points on $S^3$ like on a great $2$-sphere. In fact, every *three* points on $S^3$ lie on a great $2$-sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to try to answer your question in the title.
Because $(S^3,S^2)$ is a 2-connected CW-pair and $S^2$ is 1-connected. By Excision Theorem, we would have an isomorphism
$$\pi_i(X,A)\to\pi_i(X/A), \ i\leq (2+1)=3$$
Then if we write the long exact sequence of the pair $(S^3,S^2)$, we get
$$\cdots\to\pi_1(S^3)=0\to\pi_1(S^3,S^2)\cong\pi_1(S^3/S^2)\to\pi_0(S^2)=0\to\pi_0(S^3)=0\to\cdots$$
This tells us that $$\pi_1(S^3,S^2)\cong\pi_1(S^3/S^2)=0\neq\pi_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$$
Hence $S^3/S^2$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. It cannot be homeomorphic to $S^1$ either.